# Change lib source code without destroying it

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So, as I found the patched source code for **BodyEditorLoader.java**, I am not able to do any changes in the .java file. How to I edit it without destroying the library? Thanks!

Comment: Where did you find the source code? If you're using Eclipse, you could just edit the Java file in the library and run the android application project, and your changes to the library would be effected.

Comment: iRuth, I am actually using Android Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope to explain well, a simple way would be to create a new class, copy the contents of the BodyEditorLoader class, except class package name `package aurelienribon.bodyeditor;`, and rename `public class BodyEditorLoader` by the name of your class, for example MyBodyEditorLoader. example:

```
//package aurelienribon.bodyeditor;  --> change or delete for your packege name

package com.tynibattles04.game;    //--> in your case for example.

import com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.CircleShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.PolygonShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonValue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyBodyEditorLoader {
    //...other code
    public MyBodyEditorLoader(FileHandle file) {
    //...other code
    }

    public MyBodyEditorLoader(String str) {
    //...other code
    }
    //..other code
```

and used (and import, if you need it necessary):

```
MyBodyEditorLoader loader = new MyBodyEditorLoader(
                          Gdx.files.internal("tankA.json"));
```